# Does TIBCO EMS Support STOMP Transport protocol?

Tags: tibco, stomp, tibco-ems

We'd like to use STOMP to hit an EMS broker, and avoid the complexity of JMS. Is this idea at all possible with EMS?

Answer (score 6):

As far as i know it's only possible with TIBCO's 3rd party WebSocket Gateway from Kaazing.

Have a look [here](https://kaazing.com/doc/5.0/jms_client_docs/apidoc/client/dotnet/jms/html/N_Kaazing_JMS_Stomp.htm)

Answer (score 3):

TIBCO offers "Tibco Web Messaging (TWM)" which is a re-branded ["Kaazing WebSocket Gateway JMS Edition"](https://kaazing.com/products/websocket-gateway/editions/).

The Kaazing Gateway talks STOMP to EMS on the backend, and accepts WebSocket connections with a blindingly fast binary protocol from clients.  You can have Java, Javascript, .Net (including Xamarin) or iOS clients.  Details of how to write clients and supported JMS APIs are [here on the Kaazing site](https://kaazing.com/getting-started/).

If you are looking for a pure STOMP solution, there is a [Node STOMP module](https://nodejsmodules.org/pkg/stomp) but I'm not as familiar with quality client implementations there.